# Form inputs disabled

Tags: html, forms

I have two forms on my page, I wrapped the first with a new class just to restrict it to span5, and from that the forms now appear next to each other horizontally but the first is not allowing you to click into or on the elements at all.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="greybg-container">
                <div class="span5">
                <div id="login-container">
                        <div class="inner-content">
                            <h4>Login</h4>

                                <div class="basket-login"><div class="basket-login-text"><?php $seintro = new Page($db,'SiteElements','Login'); echo $seintro->row['pageCopy']; ?></div>
                                <form method="post" action="<?php echo HTTP_HOST; ?>Site/MyAccount/Login/?basketId=<?php echo $_REQUEST['basketId'] ? $_REQUEST['basketId'] : $basket->row['orderId']; ?>&amp;wishlist=<?php echo $_GET['wishlist']; ?>&amp;categoryId=<?php echo $_GET['categoryId']; ?>&addToBasketSize=<?php echo $_GET['addToBasketSize']; ?>">
                                <?php if ($errorLogin){ ?>
                                <span class="error"><?php echo $errorLogin; ?></span>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <table class="basket">
                                    <?php foreach($form_login as $each){ ?>
                                    <tr><td class="title"><?php $each->writeLabel(); ?></td>
                                    <td><?php $each->write(); ?></td></tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="title">
                                        <label for="login_userSubmit"></label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="form_button">
                                        <input id="login_userSubmit" type="submit" size="" value="Send" onclick="" name="login_userSubmit">
                                        <br>
                                        <a class="grey-link" href="<?php echo HTTP_HOST; ?>Site/MyAccount/ForgotPassword">Forgot Password ?</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                    <div id="left">
                    <div class="inner-content">
                        <h4>Register</h4>

                           <div class="basket-login"><div class="basket-login-text"><?php $seintro = new Page($db,'SiteElements','Register'); echo $seintro->row['pageCopy']; ?><?php echo $page->row['pageCopy']; ?></div></div>           
                           <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                    <?php if (is_array($error)){ ?>
                                    <strong>Please Note :</strong> The following errors have occurred
                                        <ul>
                                        <?php foreach($error as $id=>$each){ ?>
                                            <li class="error"><?php $form_signup[$id]->writeLabel($each); ?></li>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <table class="basket">
                                    <?php if($form_signup){ foreach($form_signup as $each){ ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="title"><?php $each->writeLabel(); ?></td>
                                            <td><?php $each->write(); ?></td>
                                    <?php } } ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="title">
                                            <label for="signup_submit"></label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="form_button">
                                            <input style="width:auto;" id="signup_submit" type="submit" size="" value="Continue Registration" onclick="document.getElementById('action_submit').value='1';document.submit();" name="signup_submit">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>

                        </form>

                    </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

the second form starts where there is div id="left". ignore the fact it says left, that's the form on the right as you'll see.

http://bit.ly/19fegdi

Comment: Wow a table layout. I remember seeing somewhere that table layouts are things of the past and should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span5 is overlapped by the form which on the right side. Add the following css style will fix it.

```
#left{
 float: left;
}
```